# I can't print with conditional if

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a problem with "if":

```
<%= print 'Hi American people' if @people.country == "Usa" %>
```

When I preview my app, I cannot see the message "hi american people": the field is blank.

Comment: Are you using the `print` statement on purpose here? You want it to print to the console and not to the html page?

Comment: print html, i fixed ` <%= "Hi American people" if @people.country == "Usa" %>`

Answer (score 3):

Using `print` will print to the console and won't actually display anything in your HTML file.

Below, we can use an if "block". In the "block", you can put any HTML within.

```
<% if @people.country == "Usa" %>
  Hi American people
<% end %>
```

For example, I can do the following, adding multiple HTML elements within. They will only display if the conditional passes:

```
<% if @people.country == "Usa" %>
  <span>Hi American people</span>
  <p>Today is a good day..</p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: @Stefan I used it as a demonstration to show any html element can go inside, but will go ahead and edit and clarify my post